# Solve $z^5 = 32$ (include complex solutions)

Tags: complex-numbers

Question:

> Solve $z^5 =32$ (including complex solutions)

My Working :

> $$
> z^5=32
> $$
>   $$
> z^5=32cis(0+2k\pi)
> $$
>   $$
> z=2cis(0+\frac{2k\pi}5)
> $$
>   I then went through all the solutions for $k=0\to4$ which gave me the solutions of:
>   $$
> 2,\space2cis(0+\frac{2\pi}5),\space2cis(0+\frac{4\pi}5),\space2cis(0+\frac{6\pi}5),\space2cis(0+\frac{8\pi}5)
> $$

Could someone confirm for me that this is correct, and if not where I have gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your solutions are correct.

Comment: Idea is right, but the last line only lists approximations. Are you being asked for exact solutions, and if so then in trigonometric or algebraic form?

Comment: @dxiv not specified so I just decided to give it to two decimals

Comment: @Conal In math contexts, "not specified" usually means exact forms. I would assume this is not the *first* question of its kind you have ever been posed, so maybe look back and see what the expectation is.

Comment: @dxiv previous questions have been left in polar form

Comment: @dxiv will do, thanks for the help mate, just edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex solutions to your problem is $2e^{\dfrac{i2k\pi}{5}}$ where $k=0,1,2,3,4$

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I should have specified what prior knowledge I have this is a revision question for my high school class with no answer so I thought I would put it on here to confirm.

Comment: Sorry but I do not have the privilege to comment on other's questions, hence I had to comment on my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the solutions are indeed
$$z_k = 2{\rm e}^{2k\pi{\rm i}/5}=2{\rm cis}\Bigl({2k\pi\over 5}\Bigr)=2\Bigl(\cos\Bigl({2k\pi\over 5}\Bigr)+{\rm i}\sin\Bigl({2k\pi\over 5}\Bigr)\Bigr),\qquad k=0,1,2,3,4$$
But as the angles ${2\pi k \over 5}=k\cdot 72^\circ$ have explicit values for cosine and sine, the solutions can also be written as
$$z_1 = 2\Bigl({\sqrt 5 - 1\over 4}+{\rm i}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt 5} \over 4}\Bigr)$$
$$z_2 = 2\Bigl(-{\sqrt 5 + 1 \over 4}+{\rm i}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt 5}\over 4}\Bigr) $$
together with $z_0 = 2$, $z_3 = \bar z_2$, and $z_4 = \bar z_1$.